# postgresql st_asgeojson returns not readable value

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geojson

I'm trying to make this data to geometry, but for some reason postgresql returns not readable values. I need latlng.... I can't use that value to draw marker at all.

what am i missing here?

please help.

postgresql v. 11

`insert into area(latlng) values('0101000000A0ABA80D249D024100EC624219AA0B41'::geometry);`

`select st_asgeojson(latlng) from area;`

returns

`"{""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[152484.50666937,226627.157415241]}"`

----------------------------------------- added

more queries are added. they always return same value.
I'm started thinking the value that I provided from data team, might be wrong...('0101000000A0ABA80D249D024100EC624219AA0B41')

`select ST_AsText('0101000000A0ABA80D249D024100EC624219AA0B41');`
`"POINT(152484.50666936953 226627.157415241)"`

`select st_setsrid(st_asgeojson('0101000000A0ABA80D249D024100EC624219AA0B41')::geometry, 4326);`

[image]

`select st_transform(st_setsrid(st_asgeojson('0101000000A0ABA80D249D024100EC624219AA0B41'::geometry), 4326), 3857);`
[image]

Comment: A large part of GIS is the projection that the data is encoded in.   Can you do `select st_srid(latlng) from area;` and add it.  You may need to use `st_transform` to tranform it into a different projection (e.g. WGS84, which is identified as srid 4326, is probably lat/lng). Probably searching up a bunch of these terms might help. ;-)

Comment: @GregHNZ Hey!! Thank you so much for the comment! I've tested with your suggestion and then now it returns `ERROR: transform: Invalid coordinate(2049)` ... should I contact with data team...?

Comment: @ChaehwaRyu perhaps you've mistakenly created the coordinates as `lat long`? It should be `long lat` (x,y)

Comment: @JimJones Thanks for the opinion! but i've got that data from the data team. I didn't make it. I have zero idea how they converted. i'm just trying to convert  it back to latlng(lnglat). I guess this one is just poor as other datasets they provided. I'll check it out!! :) have a great day!

Comment: these coordinates are clearly not in 4326 (+-180 / +-90). You need to know the SRID so you can 1) set it and 2) convert via st_stransform to 4326. Also you don't set the SRID (nor do anything) on the geojson but on the original geometry

Comment: @ChaehwaRyu these coordinates do not seem to be WGS84  .. check with your team the SRS. Cheers and happy coding!

Comment: Your'e getting the error in your last query because you're giving st_setsrid a geojson string rather than a geometry. Leave out the st_asgeojson.

Comment: @mlinth (pedantic note) it is not entirely accurate: https://dbfiddle.uk/A7DQSyQt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input value is `geography` and not `geometry`. See below

```sql
select st_astext('0101000000A0ABA80D249D024100EC624219AA0B41'::geography);
-- POINT(-155.4933306304738 -7.157415241003036)

select postgis_version();
-- 3.3 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

In short `geography` is more accurate but resource intensive to query.
`geometry` is the 99% good enough version of `geography`

Info:
https://postgis.net/documentation/faq/geometry-or-geography/

Comment: Sorry for late, super thanks. it works :)